# RegEx for a multiple line search and replace using sed

Tags: regex, unix, sed, ksh

I need to have a RegEx that finds a `\n` in the middle of a line as a start point, anything before is random, and replace after 15 digits and 49 alpha on the second line. I need to replace all that by blanks, but the second line needs to join with the first one.

#### Attempt

```
sed -r -e '{N;s/\n[[:digit:]]{15}[[:space:]]{49}//}'
```

#### Input

```
QC HOH 0H0 CA
:70:NOFX TRADE TR
100000100200621                                                 ADE RELATED WOOD                                                                                         PURCHASE
```

[image: Screen shot of record]

What needs to be removed is the linefeed after TRADE TR and bring the ADE RELATED to the TR so it spells TRADE.

#### Desired Output

```
QC H0H 0H0 CA
:70:NOFX TRADE TRADE RELATED WOOD                                                                                         PURCHASE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;s/\n[[:digit:]]{15}[[:space:]]{49}//;P;D' file
```

This opens up a two line window and amends the second of them if the substitute command matches. It always prints the first of the two lines and then removes it.

Comment: Wow, Thanks a bunch, I didn't know about those P and D options.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed -Ez 's/\n[[:digit:]]{15}[[:space:]]{49}//' file
QC J0B 2Y0 CA
:70:NOFX TRADE TRADE RELATED WOOD                                                                                         PURCHASE
```

Comment: I cannot try it, I'm on redhat 2.6, my sed doesn't have a -z option.